# How does SQLLDR manages multiple processes on an OS?

Tags: linux, oracle, sql-loader

in SQL Loader, I wanted to ask if anyone knows the limits on how may processes in an OS can be initiated at one time?

For Example, I have code which spins off 20 processes to load 20 sets of data at the same time, and each process spins a new SQL Loader.

Each set to the same table in oracle. So at first call, the SQL Loader.exe on the OS is given 20 things to load.

Would that result in 20 separate instances of sqlldr processes ? or does SQL Loader queue each call to a singular process? I'm trying to determine if there's a bottleneck in this process and if I should build a way to control when each process is uploading instead of bombarding sqlldr.

ctl file is not direct load, table is not external.

Oracle 12 and Red Hat Linux Server.

I looked at this: [Does Oracle sqlldr process multiple INFILE in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770727/does-oracle-sqlldr-process-multiple-infile-in-parallel) but I'm not sure where the docs are that explain that answer and i've been looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL loader is a single process. If you want to parallelize your load, you need to run multiple sql loader processes concurrently. You will also need the parallel=true directive in your control file.

However, in many cases, it’s much easier and more efficient to use external tables.

Comment: thanks man - i thought so, i read so, but what i kinda want to know is that, if there was 300 different sql loader processes running - would that crash or is that even possible?

Comment: @Peyter It will depend on what physical resources you have. Data loading is typically CPU bound, (unless you are loading over a slow neetwork), so you would need a 300 core machine to run 300 concurrent loader processes. But it's possible, and I have done it in the past.

Comment: thats great to know, i needed that confirmation, even after reading. BobC FTW :)))